# Database: what design to have a "document table" referencing others tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I have some tables which can have `0..*` documents.

How can I design my data model without specify the table fields in the `document` table? Feel free to suggest [by editing the data model](https://yuml.me/edit/ca7c541f)

[image]
<sub>(source: [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/ca7c541f))</sub>

Comment: That sounds like standard normalization.  Please change "my_table" to some specific example like "Authors" and "Contents" -- _IF_ that is what you are thinking.  Otherwise it looks like an awful schema.

Comment: @RickJames "my_table_n" were only here as exemple. The tables have no relation between them like update above : car, house, fruit, author, ... I think that there could be a design to avoid to specify the table FK in the document table by adding some "parent" table where other tables could inherits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some tables which can have 0..* documents.

I am assuming that car, house, fruit, author ... are some tables having documents.
 I will suggest having a parent table called `Documentary` for these element. This documentary table will have zero-or-one relation to all of these tables. A record in documentary table will show one and only one record in one of other tables.
Documentary table will have a type field showing its related record type.
Having FK of Documentary inside document table will solve the problem.
(In OOP terminology Documentary will be an abstract entity)
[image]

Comment: @Mosen Heydari Thanks for your answer.Your solution is the best I received and should works.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this sort of schema

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the real tables' names are not my_table_X. Furthermore, I want to have a foreign key from document table on my tables, which is not possible with your design

Comment: Ok. Will changing the table_num field to table_name and keeping the name of your respective my_table_X in that field do the job?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case, the integrity of FK would not be enforced by the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably each of your `my_table_n` tables contains rows referring to different documents.  You can format those rows like this:

```
 id            (surrogate PK)
 document_id   (FK to document table)
 data          whatever information you need in this table.
```

Then, you can fetch your document with the extra data, like this:

```
 SELECT d.something, d.another_thing,
        t1.data, t2.other_data, t3.more_data, t4.too_much_data
   FROM document d
   LEFT JOIN mytable_1 t1 ON d.id = t1.document_id
   LEFT JOIN mytable_2 t2 ON d.id = t2.document_id
   LEFT JOIN mytable_3 t3 ON d.id = t3.document_id
   LEFT JOIN mytable_4 t4 ON d.id = t4.document_id
```

Comment: Thanks @Ollie Jones. In fact, as I can have unlimited number of documents, the my_table_n tables don't refer to the documents, but document table refer to the my_table_n. In my document table, I want have foreign keys on the my_table_n, but I don't want to have a dedicated field for each of the my_table_n.